# can't get nested forEach to work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nested

So I guess the title is selfexplanatory. I have some code with nested `forEach` loops inside it. The loops are iterating over an array of `chapter` objects. Each object can have multiple child nodes and they again can have multiple child nodes, and so on.

I want to end up with one array which contains nested arrays with the child nodes.

So far my code looks like this:

```
exports.chapter = function(req, res) {
    var chapters = [],
        result = [];

    chapters = exports.index(req, res);

    chapters.forEach(function(chapter) {
        if(chapter.orphan){
            result.add({
                'chapter': chapter,
                'children': getChildren(chapter.children)
            });
        }
    });

    function getChildren(siblings) {
        var children = [];

        chapters.forEach(function(chapter) {
            if($.inArray(chapter, siblings)){
                children.add({
                    'chapter': chapter,
                    'children': getChildren(chapter.children)
                });
            }
        });

        return children;
    };
};
```

I don't get any errors except for my page not loading. It doesn't write anything in my console. I think it's a problem in the setup but I'm unable to find out where at the moment. Really hope you guys can help.

Comment: You should use `filter()` and `map()` instead

Comment: @SLaks: Can I convince you to give an example of what would be a better solution for my problem, with `filter()` or `map()`?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely problem is here:

```
if($.inArray(chapter, siblings)){
```

`$.inArray` is a horribly misnamed method: It returns an *index*, or -1 if not found, not a flag as the name implies. -1 is, of course, truthy; and `0` (a valid index), is falsey, so your `if` probably wants to be

```
if($.inArray(chapter, siblings) != -1){
    // We found it...
}
```

or possibly

```
if($.inArray(chapter, siblings) == -1){
    // We didn't find it
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. It doesn't seem to have fixed the problem

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard: I couldn't quite follow what you were trying to achieve in the loops. I guess the above is only *part* of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange.. I don't understand why you're using 'add' instead of 'push' method. If I try to "add" an object to an array I get an usual error. Don't you?

Comment: changing `.add` to `.push` sure fixed the webpage loading ;-) However when I try calling this method I get a and error telling me it failed to load ressource, and then I just keep getting a `socket.io` error. I don't get any information what the error is, or where in my code it's at. Strange.